# Algorithm Of Shifted In Column : shift the letters doesn't work

Tags: java, algorithm

I want to create a two-dimensional array to enter the alphabet and then shift the letters to the next value in the array. So I have the following program:

```
public class AlgorithmOfShiftedInColumn {
public static char[] alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray();

/**
 * source : http://www.codeurjava.com/2017/10/java-supprimer-un-element-dun-tableau.html
 * @param a     array
 * @param del   index of the item to delete
 */
public static void removeElement(char[] a, int del) {
    System.arraycopy(a,del+1,a,del,a.length-1-del);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[][] arrayAlgorithm = new char[26][26];
    for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
        arrayAlgorithm[i] = alphabet;
        char temporaryLetter;
        temporaryLetter = alphabet[0];
        removeElement(alphabet, 0);
        alphabet[alphabet.length - 1] = temporaryLetter;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(arrayAlgorithm[i]);
    }
}
```

However, instead of printing the array as I want it:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZA
CDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZAB
[...]
```

it shows me instead:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
[...]
```

After trying to do some debugging, I noticed that the changes to the *alphabet* also had an effect on the elements in my *arrayAlgorithm* array while I was not modifying it.
Do you have any idea of the reason for this problem? Do you have a way to avoid it or some other way of doing what I want more easily?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not created a new copy of **alphabet** array **arrayAlgorithm[i]** points to the same reference location  as alphabet so the existing array also gets changed . Use **copyOf** for creating a new copy of the array.

`Array.copyOf()` allocates a new array object on the heap (of the size specified by the second argument), copies the contents of your existing array to it, then returns the reference to that new array to you.

```java
arrayAlgorithm[i] = Arrays.copyOf(alphabet,alphabet.length);
```

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks a lot!